# Uncaught PHP Exception MongoDB\Driver\Exception\AuthenticationException: "Authentication failed."

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, docker-compose

### Description:

I'm trying to drop a mongo collection in my Symfony application, however I get an "authentication fails" when I try to drop a collection. I'm able to **select a database** and I'm able to **select a collection**.

The mongoUrl connection string that I inject into my MongoService uses the same credentials specified in my docker compose:

```
mongodb://root:XXX@redaph_mongo_1:27017
```

*Note: That even when I put in the wrong credentials I'm still able to select a database and collection without any error being thrown.*

### Question:

Why am I getting "Authenticaion Fails" when I try to drop a collection when I'm using root credentials?
How do I correctly authenticate with the root username and password?

### Error:

> [2018-06-21 08:45:41] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   MongoDB\Driver\Exception\AuthenticationException: "Authentication
>   failed." at
>   /var/www/redaph/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/DropCollection.php
>   line 108 {"exception":"[object]
>   (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\AuthenticationException(code: 11):
>   Authentication failed. at
>   /var/www/redaph/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/DropCollection.php:108)"}
>   []

### Relevant code:

**docker-compose.yml snippet**

```
version '3':
  services:
    mongo:
      image: mongo
      restart: always
      environment:
        MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
        MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: "XXX"
      volumes:
        - mdb_data:/data/db
```

**MongoService.php snippet:**

```
class MongoService
{
    const QUESTION_RESPONSE_COLLECTION = "question_response";
    const DATABASE_NAME = "redaph";
    private $mongoDB;

    public function __construct($mongoUrl)
    {
        $mongoClient = new MongoClient($mongoUrl);

        $this->mongoDB = $mongoClient->selectDatabase(self::DATABASE_NAME);

    }

    private function getQuestionResponseCollection(){
        return $this->mongoDB->selectCollection(self::QUESTION_RESPONSE_COLLECTION);
    }


    public function generateQuestionResponses(){

        /** code here to populate $questionResponses **/

        $collection = $this->getQuestionResponseCollection();
        #-> Authentication Fails Here
        $collection->drop();
        $results = $collection->insertMany($questionResponses);
        return $results->getInsertedCount();
    }

    public function getQuestionResponses(){
        return $this->getQuestionResponseCollection()->find([]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a thorough investigation on the matter, I changed how my MongoService worked and I emptied my mongo volume.

The main issue was that I had changed the password a while back after creating the container.

MongoService.php

```
class MongoService
{
    const QUESTION_RESPONSE_COLLECTION = "question_response";
    const DATABASE_NAME = "redaph";
    private $mongoDB;

    public function __construct($mongoUrl, $mongoUsername, $mongoPassword)
    {
        $mongoClient = new MongoClient($mongoUrl, ["authMechanism" => "SCRAM-SHA-1", "username" => $mongoUsername, "password" => $mongoPassword]);
        $this->mongoDB = $mongoClient->selectDatabase(self::DATABASE_NAME);
    }
}
```

services.yml

```
parameters:
    locale: 'en'
    env(MONGO_URL): 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27107'
    env(MONGO_USERNAME): ''
    env(MONGO_PASSWORD): ''
services:
    App\Service\MongoService:
        arguments:
            $mongoUrl: '%env(resolve:MONGO_URL)%'
            $mongoUsername: '%env(resolve:MONGO_USERNAME)%'
            $mongoPassword: '%env(resolve:MONGO_PASSWORD)%'
```

Comment: Even I faced the issue today, I had changed the password and assumed that restarting the service would do the charm but, it was not that case. I had to stop the service and then start it again.

Answer (score 2):

this issue is occur due to using the wrong username or password. please check both but remember the one thing do not  use a special character in passwords because they used encoding so that maybe create an issue for you

Comment: I have faced the same issue today, I just remove a special character from the password, and now it's up. Thank you.

Comment: yeah maybe  when mongo encoding method generate issue